# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3090 >= 3090 at java.util.Vector.elementAt

Tags: java, arrays, libsvm

I get

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3090 >= 3090
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
```

when I run piece of code below. Any help welcome.

```
prob = new svm_problem();
prob.l = vy.size();
prob.x = new svm_node[prob.l][];
for(int i=0;i<prob.l;i++)
    prob.x[i] = vx.elementAt(i);
prob.y = new double[prob.l];
for(int i=0;i<prob.l;i++)
    prob.y[i] = vy.elementAt(i);
```

Comment: This code is the ugliest I've seen. And I've seen some! Also, which is the **exact line** the error is thrown at? Some advice: 1, use meaningful names, 2, use the naming convention: CamelCased class names starting with a capital 3, use brackets around loop block bodies... (also, a minor advice, as I don't know the code surroundings: use public variables sparingly, and only when the context asks for that.)

Comment: @TedHopp: It's line 470 in java.util.Vector. The full stack trace is required.

Answer (score 1):

`vy.size()` is used to determine the bounds of your loops, which then access both `vx` and `vy`. It would appear that `vx` is shorter than `vy`, resulting in the exception shown.

Comment: This code is part of  libsvm-3.16 package in svm_train.java. When I train data set following this blog https://mrtextminer.wordpress.com/2008/03/03/a-practice-on-libsvm-example-in-debian-etch-using-java/#comment-535 this exception occured

Answer (score 0):

You use `i` to index `vx` while it iterates from 0 to `vy.size() - 1`.  If `vy` is larger than `vx` this will lead to an exception similar to what you have.

Answer (score 0):

`prob.l` is the size of `vy`, you need to find the size of `vx` as well.

```
for(int i=0;i<vx.size();i++)
    prob.x[i] = vx.elementAt(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You loop on vx from 0 to prob.l-1, but prob.l is based on the size of vy, which seems to be bigger.